# what is the pshared value of a semaphore if I used sem_open() instead of sem_init()?

Tags: c, posix, semaphore, multiple-processes

I am currently working on the dining philosophers problem using semaphores and processes, and I used `sem_open()` function to create semaphores instead of `sem_init()`. And since the `sem_open()` doesn't take the `pshared` value as a parameter.
Could somebody give me a good explanation how the semaphores are shared between processes when using `sem_open()`? I thought that maybe because the semaphore is opened in the file system but some more clarification would be most appreciated .

Comment: A named semaphore is inherently shared between processes that open it.

Comment: i needed the term `named semaphore` in my search, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Linux/glibc, POSIX semaphores are implemented with the pthread mutexes which are based on the [futexes](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/futex.2.html). The *pshared* parameter relates to the mutex attribute passed to [pthread_mutexattr_setpshared](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutexattr_setpshared). The possible values are:

- **PTHREAD_PROCESS_PRIVATE** for mutexes internal to the process (this is the default in the pthread library);
- **PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED** for mutexes shared between any threads that have access to the memory containing the object, including threads in different processes.

When a semaphore is created with `sem_open()`, it is considered shareable between processes and threads. That is to say, it behaves like `sem_init()` when we set *pshared* to non-zero.
Internally, `sem_open()` creates a file in */dev/shm* into which a *sem_t* structure is stored. The file is mapped in the calling process memory with a call to `mmap(NULL, sizeof (sem_t), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0)` where *fd* is the file descriptor of the opened file. So, this is how the semaphore is shared between processes as they all map the same file content in their address space.
As a side note, the value returned by `sem_open()` is the address of the memory mapped *sem_t* structure from the underlying file.